# Android Google Maps Increase/decreas radius after adding

Tags: android, google-maps, radius

Right now this is my code for my Android App. It adds a marker on the Google Maps when Long Click, then when you click on the marker it creates a circle marker and removes the normal marker. However I want to adjust the radius of the circle when I add it. Like incrase or decrease it when I move my finger up or down.

```
    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {

            MarkerOptions Marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng);

            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

            mMap.addMarker(Marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.human)).draggable(true));
        }
    });



    @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

            LatLng pos = marker.getPosition();
            marker.remove();
            mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                    .center(pos)
                    .radius(radius)
                    .strokeColor(0xFFF7941D)
                    .fillColor(0x90F7941D));

            return true;
        }
```

Sorry, but does anyone know how to or where I can read more about? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

```
`googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition pos) {

            // do your action here
        }
    }
});`
```

to change the radius inside the marker event.
hope this will help you

Comment: Sorry, I am quite the newbie to Android.
Could you tell me more about it?

Comment: 1- initialize an instance variable called radius in your activity
2-add the above code into your onMarkerClick() method
3-inside onCamerChange() method check if returned value pos == marker pos then change the radius variable to increase it or decrease it.
cheers

Comment: Right now it works. However I can only see the changes as I lift up my finger from the screen. Is it possible to see the changes as I move the finger up and down on the screen?